# Python read data in as binary

Tags: python

I am wanting to read in the logData as binary and then parse the binary output in the second for loop as it is for a string but for binary. Is this possible?

```
logData = open(sys.argv[1]).readlines()
processedSources = sys.stdin.readlines()

stringDictionary = {}
for line in processedSources:
    # Match data looking for MODULE_ID, LOG_LINE, ARG_COUNT, FILE_NAME, DATA_STRING
    match = re.search("(\d+),\s+(\d+),\s+(\d+),\s+(.*),\s+(\".*\")", line)
    if match:
        moduleId = int(match.group(1))
        logLine = int(match.group(2))
        argCount = int(match.group(3))
        fileName = match.group(4)
        outputString = match.group(5)    
        stringDictionary[(moduleId, logLine)] = [ moduleId, logLine, argCount, fileName, outputString ]
    else:
        print "Failed string dictionary on: " + line

for line in logData:
    # Match data looking for MODULE_ID, LOG_LINE, ARG_COUNT, ARGUMENTS
    matchLogData = re.split("\s+", line)
    if matchLogData:
        moduleId = int(matchLogData[0], 16)
        logLine = int(matchLogData[1], 16)
        argCount = int(matchLogData[2], 16)
        if stringDictionary[(moduleId, logLine)]:
            processedData = stringDictionary[(moduleId, logLine)]
            if argCount != processedData[2]:
                print "Argument count mismatch on : " + line
                print "   expected %d found %d" % (argCount, processedData[2])
            else:
                index = 0
                logString = "%02x:%4d:%s:" + processedData[4]
                logData = (processedData[0], processedData[1], processedData[3])
                while index < argCount:
                    logData = logData + (int(matchLogData[index+3], 16),)
                    index = index + 1
                print logString % logData
        else:
            print "ModuleId:%d Line:%d, not found in source dictionary" % (moduleId, logLine)
            print "   Line data: " + line
    else:
        print "Expected log input data mismatch MODULE_ID LOG_LINE ARG_COUNT ARGS"
        print "Line: " + line
```

Comment: `logData = open(sys.argv[1],"rb").readlines()`

Comment: `readlines` does apparently interpret the input as text. Binary data is not structured as lines. Use `read()` instead in the loop (no iterator).

Comment: @JoranBeasley: `readlines` is of little use with binary data.

Comment: Please specify if you are using Python 3 or 2. There are some differences for such processing for both languages.

Comment: Why do you need to open the log data as binary? Are there still line separators (`\n` or `\r` or `\n\r`) in the data?

Comment: @MartijnPieters it would still split on "\r","\n" etc :P ... since he is using newlines lines as his delimiter

Comment: @MartijnPieters: IIRC Python 2 does not interpret text diffently on Linux. It just relies on the libc of the system.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: sure, but if the data is truely binary, that may not be the case. And it depends on the OS how `readlines()` behaves in that case.

Comment: In text mode, `\r` might very well be swallowed (possibly only after `\n`, but still a problem..

Comment: @Olaf: I believe it depends on the Python version (certainly as far as line separator behaviour goes), and the OP hasn't given us any OS context either.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Tha'ts why I asked him. But apparently he is not that much interested in joining the discussion.

Comment: I did readlines just now to check ... I still got alot of binary non-ascii data and it still split on `"\r","\n",etc.` so calling `readlines` did not treat it as text ... its just effectively the same `re.split("[\r\n]+",f.read())`.... which may or maynot be meaningful with binary data

Comment: @JoranBeasley: The underlying libc can very well swallow CR for instance. Not sure about the others, though. In P3, it might even translate the text encoding due to extended uniccode support. Too many "what if" and "might" for my taste. Just do not do it this way.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: did you test this on Windows, Linux, and Mac? What Python versions? Python 3 has overhauled the I/O object hierarchy entirely.

Comment: yeah im still in python2 and it was windows ... so readlines may change behaviour depending on python version or OS ... I still havent seen an example where it stripped out all the non-ascii

Comment: as far as Im aware readlines is simply read ... but split on newline characters .... If that is what the OP wants (as implied by the original code) than who am I too say that that is not what he wants... sure you might have newlines in the binary data which will cause funny splits... but lets assume this is binary data that was generated to specifically avoid newline characters inside the binary payload (so that it could use newlines as a delimiter)

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Even if `readline()` would do no actual harm, It actually does present a performance penality as it has to buffer the read and parse the input for line breaks. Also, it does hide the "binary data"-semantics, In Python 3, you actually would read binary data into a bytearray (well, that does exist in Python 2, too, but is often treated here like an unwanted child). readline does return `str`, however, with all implications on encoding, etc. My conclusion: hands off!